# Can I use an official Client Library create a new Google Form?

Tags: node.js, curl, google-api, google-forms

I'm considering using the Google Forms API to automate a process, but I'm getting unclear messages from [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest):

> To call this service, we recommend that you use the Google-provided [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

I've looked at 3 "client libraries" from that link and I haven't been able to find mention of the Google Forms API. Here's [the Node.js reference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference), and that page doesn't even contain the word, "Forms."

Since I've never done something like this before, I'm wondering if I should be looking for something else in the client library? Or maybe, the recommendation to use a client library is copied and pasted on every Google API regardless of feasibility?

If there is a way to use this Node.js client library to read and write to the Google Forms API, can someone show me a hello world example? Perhaps a way to use the client library to create a new form with minimal (zero would suffice) questions?

If this can't be done with the Node.js client library, can it be done with another client library? If so, which? Can I see a hello world example of using it to create a Google form?

If my original assessment is correct and it's not possible to do this with a client library, can somebody show me a hello world example using curl or JavaScript's `fetch`?

Instead of hand waving away the auth details, I'd like to see functioning auth code in your example (remove the actual secret keys, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to help you with copying and renaming Google Forms using JavaScript

Google Apps Script is just a JavaScript with built-in APIs and functionalities for working with Google products such as Google Forms, Gmail, and Drive.

It is likely that this is the API you're looking for,
[Google Forms API](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides)

> The Google Forms API is a RESTful interface that lets you create and >modify forms and quizzes, retrieve form responses and quiz grades, set >up quiz answer keys with automatic feedback, and receive push >notifications. The most common uses of this API include the following >tasks:
>
> - Create a form
> - Update a form

this guide should help you get up to speed with creating and copying Google Forms
[Creating a form](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/create-form-quiz)

here is a code snippet of creating a Google Forms that had title field

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const google = require('@googleapis/forms');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');

async function runSample(query) {
  const authClient = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'credentials.json'),
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  });
  const forms = google.forms({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: authClient,
  });
  const newForm = {
    info: {
      title: 'Creating a new form in Node',
    },
  };
  const res = await forms.forms.create({
    requestBody: newForm,
  });
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  runSample().catch(console.error);
}
module. Exports = runSample;
```

If you are going use a client library to work with Google Forms, this guide should help you [Installing a client library](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/libraries)
and look at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer to help you navigate and explore Google's API,

I hope it helps

Comment: That's very useful. Thank you. I'd like to know if it's possible to do this with a client library as it will help me navigate the Google documentation.